# How to access object thet generated in ResourceFilter inside web api method

Tags: java, jersey

I have a web method that has a token in query string, each method uses this token to identify the requesting user.

to do this, i created a ResourceFilter with name AuthenticationFilter that gets the token from request and retrieve the user informations from database, if the user is valid it lets the method to be executed otherwise it throws an UNAUTHORIZED exception.

My question is: How can i access the user information that retrieved in AuthenticationFilter class

my web api:

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/getUserOrders")
@ResourceFilters({AuthenticationFilter.class, AllowOroginFilter.class})
public String getUserOrders(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    //I need to access Usr object that retrived in AuthenticationFilter
    /*User Usr = AuthenticationFilter.Usr;*/
    String Result = getUserOrders(Usr);
    return Result;
}
```

the ResourceFilter code:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
        public User usr = null;
        @Override
        public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {
            usr = AuthenticationUtiity.AuthenticateRequest(containerRequest);
            if(usr == null){
                Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;
                String response = "{\"Success\":false, \"Message\":\"Invalid username or password\"}";
                builder = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(response);
                throw new WebApplicationException(builder.build());
            }
            return containerRequest;
        }
    }
```

i googled about this and find out a way could be using ThreadLocal and save user into ThreadLocal and get it anywhere in that thread.

https://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/11/java-thread-local-how-to-use-and-code-sample/

is there any simpler way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) on the `ContainerRequest`. Then in your resource method you can inject it with `@Context SecurityContext`. For the `SecurityContext` implementation, you can implement `Principal` and make it as detailed as you want. And when you get the `Principal` in your resource method, just cast it to your type. Below is an example filter:

```
@Provider
public class TestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        SecurityContext oldSec = request.getSecurityContext();

        final String username = "foobar";
        final String email = "email@email.com";
        final User user = new User(username, email);

        request.setSecurityContext(new MySecurityContext(user, oldSec.isSecure()));
        return request;
    }

    private static class MySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

        private final boolean isSecure;
        private final User user;

        public MySecurityContext(User user, boolean isSecure) {
            this.isSecure = isSecure;
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return this.user;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isUserInRole(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSecure() {
            return this.isSecure;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class User implements Principal {

        private final String email;
        private final String username;

        public User(String username, String email) {
            this.username = username;
            this.email = email;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the resource method

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    public String get(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
        TestFilter.User user = (TestFilter.User) sc.getUserPrincipal();
        return user.getEmail();
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

> thank you for the answer but i dont want to add extra argument to my web method

Then inject it as a field

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @Context
    private SecurityContext sc;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        TestFilter.User user = (TestFilter.User) sc.getUserPrincipal();
        return user.getEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i dont want to add extra argument to my web method

Comment: See my update... FYI, you could inject the `UriInfo` as a field also if you wanted.